# convert multiple instances of a character to only one (aa = a) using preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a string, I want to convert multiple appearances of `-` to just one `-`.

I have tried `preg_replace('/--+/g', '-', $string)` but that simply returns nothing..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `g` in the pattern, and you can simplify your regular expression:

```
preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string);
```

Backslash escapes are not required.

On http://ideone.com/IOlpv:

```
<?
$string = "asdfsdfd----sdfsdfs-sdf-sdf";
echo preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string);
?>
```

Output:

```
asdfsdfd-sdfsdfs-sdf-sdf
```

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_replace('/([\-]+)/', '-', $string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code gives the following error:

> Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g'

There is no `g` modifier. Try:

```
preg_replace('/--+/', '-', $string)
```